# R 64-bit will not start on Windows 10

Tags: r, windows

I am using Windows 10 enterprise and having problems running 64-bit R on my computer. When I started R-Studio this morning I got an error: `The R session failed to start.` and `The R session process exited with code -1073740791`. The log for this error is:

```
ERROR system error 10053 (An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine) [request-uri: /events/get_events]; 
OCCURRED AT void __thiscall rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) src/cpp/session/http/SessionWin32HttpConnectionListener.cpp:113; 
LOGGED FROM: void __thiscall rstudio::session::HttpConnectionImpl<class rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>::sendResponse(const class rstudio::core::http::Response &) src/cpp/session/http/SessionWin32HttpConnectionListener.cpp:118
```

I then tried to start 64-bit RGui (R x64 4.0.4) from the Start menu. It started for less than a second before it automatically quit. I then uninstalled and re-installed both, and I had the same errors. I've had this happen a couple of times before and I'm not sure how to problem-solve here.

**EDIT**: This problem appears only for R 4.0.3 and 4.0.4. Everything seems to work fine with R 4.0.2.

Comment: The question/title says R but the error message is from RStudio. Which is it (they are completely distinct pieces of software!)?

Comment: It's R, since even when I tried to launch R gui, it failed ("I then tried to start 64-bit R (R x64 4.0.4) from the Start menu. It started for less than a second before it automatically quit"). I first noticed the problem when using RStudio.

Comment: Given that R.4.0.2 seems to work fine, maybe looking at the new features of 4.0.3 will give you some insights on why this happens. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/NEWS.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, persumably due to an Enterprise version which restricts something (firwall, malware scanning?) after an update to a newer version of Windows. IT is investigating.

My workaround for now is to use the 32-bit version of R. Press the Ctrl key when opening RStudio and select the 32bit version of R.

Comment: Note this only works if you installed the 32-bit version.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? I have the same/a similar issue... updated windows to v1909 yesterday and then a couple of other updates happened an hour or so ago and stopped 64bit R working. R(Studio) now crashes when i click the knit button in Rmds... or when opening help files from the autocomplete menu (via F1)