# R 4.2.0 doesn't start in RStudio (Windows 11)

Tags: r, rstudio, windows-11

R 4.2.0 does not start in RStudio. Attached is the screenshot. It says, "The R session process exited with code - 1073740791" R 4.2.0 starts normally outside RStudio. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Are you running Windows 11 Enterprise?

Comment: You seem to be running an old version of RStudio. The current version for Windows is " RStudio-2022.02.2-485.exe".

Comment: Same issue as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640821/r-64-bit-will-not-start-on-windows-10

Comment: I've seen this consistently on Windows Enterprise editions.. The workaround for some has been to run 32 bit R in RStudio.  I believe the problem is 4.0.5 onward (i.e. 64bit versions <4.0.5 should run in RStudio on Windows Enterprise versions).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, dcarlson, you solved my problem. I was using RStudio 2021.09.0 and thought it was the most up-to-date because when I clicked on Check for Update, RStudio's message was that I was using the most up-to-date one. After installing RStudio 2022.02.2, the problem disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the newest version of Rstudio has some problems with R 4.2. I changed R studio to an older version, the issue disappeared.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).